# Modified Kneser-Ney Zero Weighting Factor

Tags: nlp

I’m attempting to implement the modified Kneser-Ney smoothing algorithm on  a 4-gram model.  This smoothing algorithm discounts the higher order probabilities and redistributes the discount among the lower order probabilities by multiplying the lower order probabilities by a weighting factor lambda.

$$\lambda_{low}(w_{i-n+1}^{i-1}) = \frac{D_{n,1} N_1(w_{i-n+1}^{i-1}\bullet) + D_{n,2} N_2(w_{i-n+1}^{i-1}\bullet) + D_{n,3+} N_{3+}(w_{i-n+1}^{i-1}\bullet)}{N_{1+}(\bullet w_{i-n+1}^{i-1}\bullet)}$$

The challenging i'm facing is that the lambda weighting factor is indeed zero at the higher orders, thus producing a zero probability for the n-Gram. For instance, given the following n-Gram "only seeing last word" in which "only seeing last", "seeing last", and "last" are unseen, I get a zero probability regardless of the continuation count for "word".

I've read mounds of literature on the Kneser-Ney Smoothing algorithm, but I've not found anything that specifically addresses this conundrum. Any insights on the implementation of the Kneser-Ney algorithm in such situations would be appreciated.

Comment: How can the unigram "last" be unseen? What's the sample document or sentence from which you are generating these n-grams? Please edit your question to clarify.

Comment: Thanks Emre for jumping on this so quickly.  The sample n-gram is "only seeing last word".  Only "word" appears in the training set. So all weighting factors from n-gram order 4 to 1 are zero.  I hope this clarifies.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_smoothing

Comment: Emre, so is this simply adding one for unseen n-Grams for n > 1?  This isn't mentioned in any of the papers.  My sense is that such situations are specified, but it isn't clear to me.  If you have some insights, would appreciate you sharing.

Comment: Did you implement this? Would be curious to see I am struggling with this